# Boostrap Table problema de mutiples llamadas a mi funcion

Tags: jquery, bootstrap

Tengo una tabla boostrap, configurada y funcional
en cada fila he puesto un boton que ejecutará una función y cambio de color de boton.

inicialmente sólo me funcionaba el boton el la primera página, al usar el paginador perdia la función del boton y el cambio de color.

Lo he solucionado, usando on('draw.dt') y llamando  a las funciones y verificando que botón estaba pulsado mediente una variable gobal y cambiando de color del boton.

Pero tengo un conslole.log en la funcion, que he usado para ver que todo funcionaba y detecto que la funcion se repite varias veces conforme voy usando la paginación.

He limpiado todo y os dejo un ejemplo completo... que por otra... me parece que me estoy complicando

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10-dev/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f3e99a6c02/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10-dev/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f3e99a6c02/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<h2>Manage Users</h2>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="userTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> ID </th>
      <th> Name </th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td> RICHARD </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser1" userId = "1" userName="Richard">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 2 </td>
      <td> LEONARD </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser2" userId = "2" userName="Leonard">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 3 </td>
      <td> Cris </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser3" userId = "3" userName="Cris">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 4 </td>
      <td> Eva </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser4" userId = "4" userName="eva">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 5 </td>
      <td> Paco </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser5" userId = "5" userName="Paco">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 6 </td>
      <td> Pedro </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser6" userId = "6" userName="Pedro">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 7 </td>
      <td> Susan </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser7" userId = "7" userName="Susan">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 8 </td>
      <td> April </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser8" userId = "8" userName="april">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 9 </td>
      <td> Rose </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser9" userId = "9" userName="Rose">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 10 </td>
      <td> Jenny </td>
      <td><a class="btn btn-primary selectButton" id="btnUser10" userId = "10" userName="jenny">Select</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 //boostrap table init
    $(function () {
        $("#userTable").DataTable();
  
    });
 
 
 
//boostrap table configure
$("#userTable").DataTable({
  "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "aLengthMenu": [[5, 10, 20, -1], [5, 10, 20, "All"]],
 paginate: true
 //select: true,



});
 
 // redraw table page
$('#userTable').on( 'draw.dt', function () {
    //alert( 'Table redrawn' );
 //if id (global) define, clear buttons class
 if (typeof id !== 'undefined') {
     $(".selectButton").removeClass("btn-primary");
  $(".selectButton").removeClass("btn-success");
  //and add to id button
  $("#"+id).addClass("btn-success");
 }

     $('.selectButton').click(function() {
   
   var este = this;
    myFunction(este);
    });
  
} );
 
//first page action button
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('.selectButton').click(function() {
   var este = this;
   
    myFunction(este);
  });
});
 

//function for selectbuttons
function myFunction(este) {
 var userName = $(este).attr('userName');
 //create global var
 id = $(este).attr('id');

  $(".selectButton").removeClass("btn-success");
  $(".selectButton").removeClass("btn-primary");

 $(este).addClass("btn-success");
 
 console.log(id);
}
 

  
 
 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema?

Comment: @SPock puedes dar una conclusión concreta de cual es tu problema, dices muchas cosas pero no veo cual es el problema.

Comment: Tu código se ejecuta en el snippet y parece que funciona, el log solo aparece una vez, entonces cual es el error?

Comment: Conforme se usa la paginacion, al darle a cualquier boton el console.log se va duplicando triplicando etc...

Es decir, la primera vez se muestra una vez, al cambiar de pagina, una vez, pero al seguir cambiando se va sumando una mas... eso me parece que es por que se le llama a la funcion repetidas veces, pero no veo el motivo... el objetivo es lanzar un alert... y como entendereis despues de paginar y selecionar 10 o 12 es una pesadilla.